# unable to deserialize jackson json with spring-boot

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-boot

I am trying deserialize the jackson response that I am getting from resttempalate,but it's not happening.I am not getting any error response,I am just getting null value

This is how I am calling the url

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter map = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverters.add(map);
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        Test activity=restTemplate.getForObject(url, Test.class, params);
```

Now here is my Test class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {
    @JsonProperty("message")
  private String message;

public Test(){

}
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

The json I am getting is

```
{
"id":1,
"message":"hello"
}
```

**Note that I am getting reponse if I am doing like**

```
String activity=restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, params);
```

Any help?